# Intellij cannot find dependencies inside .gradle folder

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Dependencies are in:

`.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.abc/[module name]/[version]/[hash]/[module].jar`

IntelliJ cannot find anything. Keeps complaining the things are not found.

Used `Invalidated and Restart`. Used `Synchronize`. Still not working.

How to force it to import jars inside gradle folder and fix this?

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Can you build by Gradle from command line?